# Wrong number of arguments passed python 3

Tags: python, class

I have a class that has takes 2 to 3 arguments but when I pass 1 it says only 1 has been passed but when I pass 2 it says four has been passed.

Code:

```
class GiantWarren(Warren):
  def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount):
     self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN = 200
     super(GiantWarren, self).__init__(Variability, RabbitCount, self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN)
     self.__RabbitCount = RabbitCount

  def NeedToCreateNewWarren(self):
    if self.__RabbitCount == self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

where it is called:

```
self.__Landscape[11][4].GiantWarren = GiantWarren(self.__Variability, 115)
```

gives the error

> super(GiantWarren, self).**init**(Variability, RabbitCount, self.**MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN)
>   TypeError: __init**() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

```html
class Warren:
  def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount = 0):
    self._MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN = 99
    self._RabbitCount = RabbitCount
    self._PeriodsRun = 0
    self._AlreadySpread = False
    self._Variability = Variability
```

Comment: Add the code of class `Warren`.

Comment: That's `__init__()` of `Warren` being called with three params (+ `self`)

Comment: oh, change your naming convention. you don't name things like this in python.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr While generally advised, it's not essential to follow PEP8.

Comment: @byxor no conventions are essential. however, i do recognize the importance of being consistent with the guideline of the community.

Comment: @byxor also note that two leading underscores has *behavioural* implications, not just stylistic ones.

Comment: That's a lot of code, not an [mcve]. But Warren only takes one or two arguments on initialisation, what were you expecting the third one to do?

Comment: Also, setting an instance attribute and passing it to the base initializer, doesn't look right to me.

Comment: I only want to pass two arguments but the error says I am passing 4, which doesn't make sense

Comment: The number of leading underscores is different: you set `self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN`, but the name is `Warren._MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN`. Fix that, and stop passing the value as an argument to `Warren.__init__`.

Comment: I fixed the error by removing self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN

Answer (score 1):

In the call to the superclass from class `GiantWarren`, you did:

```
super(GiantWarren, self).__init__(Variability, RabbitCount, self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN)
```

i.e. used 4 arguments (note that the current instance i.e. `self` is passed implicitly).

But the constructor of class `Warren` has the signature:

```
def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount = 0):
```

i.e. it takes 3 arguments including the instance as the first. And of the 2 others one argument is positional (mandatory) and the other is keyword with a default value (optional).

So, it seems from the naming that the `self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN` argument in the `super` call is redundant. If not, fix it your way.

---

As an aside, please try to follow PEP-8, name your classes *CamelCase* and functions/variables as *snake_case*.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many parameters being passed in via GiantWarren. You pass 4 parameters (including self):

`super(GiantWarren, self).__init__(Variability, RabbitCount, self.__MAX_RABBITS_IN_WARREN)`

... and the constructor for Warren takes 3, at most, including self:

`def __init__(self, Variability, RabbitCount = 0):`